# Apply changed environment variables to QApplication at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables, qt5, qapplication

I'm trying to run

```
qputenv("QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS", "1");
```

at runtime after an evaluation made by a QT application's MainWindow.

I'm assuming that for it the new env vars to actually apply I must close the initialized QApplication and restart it but I am unable to make it work.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int exitCode = 0;
    do
    {
        //exitCode = EXIT_CHANGE_DEBUG_FLAG; //This will make it ALWAYS work

        //Double-checking for testing only, still does not work.
        if(exitCode == EXIT_CHANGE_DEBUG_FLAG)
        {
            qputenv("QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS", "1"); // Code does fire on 2nd pass, new app/window still ignores it
        }
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        MainWindow mainWindow;
        mainWindow.show();
        exitCode = app.exec();
        //We can't change this once the app has been established.
        qputenv("QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS", "1");
        exitCode = EXIT_CHANGE_DEBUG_FLAG; //for testing only
    }
    while(exitCode == EXIT_CHANGE_DEBUG_FLAG);
    return(exitCode);
}
```

The application does restart, however it does not behave as if QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS is set.  If I move that line above QApplication it always works but I want this to be a configuration option available at runtime.

I feel like I'm trying to do either the impossible or I've overlooked something silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the environment variable at any point in your program's execution, and further calls to qgetenv will return the new value. You don't have to discard and recreate your QApplication. Just set the environment variable when the user chooses that configuration option, and it will be in effect during the rest of your application's execution time.

I think you're getting confused between what is your "application" and what QApplication is. QApplication is an object within your application. Discarding the QApplication object and creating a new one doesn't restart your overall application.

This is probably tied into confusion over the idea that your application inherits the environment when you start it, and changes to the environment outside of your application don't take effect until you stop your application. However, in this case, the qputenv call is updating YOUR application's copy of the environment. It isn't changing the external environment that you initially inherited.

Comment: The problem is the environment variable in question seems to require that it be set before a QApplication instance is generated.  If I put it at any point after a QApplication constructor call it will not work.  Doesn't matter if I completely quit & destroy destroy QApplication and re-create it which makes me think QT caches this feature in the process itself.  When I say apply in this case I don't mean accessible to the QApp (which I did confirm it is), but that core QT's library functions respond to it's existance.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that you were trying to manipulate one of QT's environment variables rather than one of your own. That's entirely possible that the value is being read from the environment when the QApplication is started and then cached from there one. That makes sense because searching the environment is much slower than just accessing an internal data member. I checked to see if there's a method to enable the debugging on the fly, and I didn't find one. I think it might not be possible to implement this feature.